# Remove leading zeros in c

Tags: c, function, gcc, zero

I want to Convert decimal into Binary but the output should be without leading zeros, so how do I remove the zeros? (The code works, it's written in C)

```
int* dec2bin(int, int[]);

main(){
  int var=0;
  int n[16];
  printf("Number(>=0, <65535): ");
  scanf("%d", &var);
  dec2bin(var, n);
  printf(" %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", n[0], n[1],n[2],n[3],n[4],n[5],n[6],n[7],n[8],n[9],n[10],n[11],n[12],n[13],n[14],n[15]);
}

int* dec2bin(int N, int n[]){
  int count = 15;
  for(count=15; count >=0; count--){
    n[count] = N%2;
    N=N/2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do not double-space code as if for proof-reading.

Comment: Print one digit at a time in a loop, skipping leading zeros?

Comment: lean more about the loops and `if`'s, for example scan from the end and return number of digits. then print in the loop in the reverse order.

Comment: you're not returning anything from `dec2bin()`

Comment: You can remove the leading zeros by printing in a loop, instead of the inline solution. You can suppress leading zeros with a flag that you test/set in the loop. Even without zero suppression, the loop would be easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding this right but, something like that?after the  N=N/2;                 an if(n==0) {break;}?

Comment: `dec2bin()` returns no value, but is declared `int*`.

Comment: There's no magic "remove leading zeroes" function. If this is for class, you're expected to think about the problem and solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues here.

- Type specifier of main() is missing. A decent compiler should give you a warning message like this: `warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]`

  - I'm not sure which standard you are using, in `C89` the default return type is assumed to be int.
  - If you change your `main()` to `int main()`, then you should return an integer value or `EXIT_SUCCESS` if you include `stdlib.h`.
  - `return 0;` indicates that program executed successfully.
- You are not returning anything from your function.

  - Well, you do not need to, since you are passing an array, the array will be modified. You are actually passing a pointer.

What you can do is loop over your array, look for the first "1" and then start printing. You can use a flag for that.

Note: If the user enters "0", just print "0", no need to call your function.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum { false, true } bool;
void dec2bin(int, int[]);

int main()
{
  int var=0;
  const int size = 16;
  int n[size];
  bool startPrinting = false;

  printf("Number(>=0, <65535): ");
  scanf("%d", &var);

  if (var == 0)
  {
    printf("0\n");
  }
  else
  {
    dec2bin(var, n);
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < size; cnt++)
    {
      if (n[cnt] == 1) // Check for the first "1" in n
      {
        startPrinting = true;
      }

      if (startPrinting)
      {
        printf("%d", n[cnt]);
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}

void dec2bin(int N, int n[]){
  int count = 15;
  for(count=15; count >=0; count--){
    n[count] = N%2;
    N=N/2;
  }
}
```

Here is some sample output:

```
> ./out 
Number(>=0, <65535): 32
100000
> ./out 
Number(>=0, <65535): 16
10000
> ./out 
Number(>=0, <65535): 15
1111
> ./out
Number(>=0, <65535): 1
1
> ./out
Number(>=0, <65535): 0
0
```

Comment: Better perhaps to use stdbool.h rather then cook your own `bool`.  Also this answer is dominated by the criticism unrelated to the question.  Perhaps reorder to answer the question, then add the helpful asides, or add them as comments to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Skip leading zeros
int d = 0 ;
for( d = 0; n[d] == 0 && d < 15; d++ )
{
    // nothing
}   

// Print significant digits
for( ; d < 16; d++ )
{
    printf( "%d ", n[d] ) ;
}
```

Note that `dec2bin` generates an array of binary digits in an `int`.  That is clearly not a conversion from *decimal to binary*, because the `int` already is binary - the `scanf()` call already did the conversion to binary (`int`) with the `%d` specifier. The function is over-complex given that it already is binary.  What you are actually doing is simply expanding single bits to an array of integer values 0 and 1.

Consider:

```
int* int2bin( int N, int n[] )
{
  for( int d = 15; d >= 0; d-- )
  {
    n[d] = (N & (0x0001 << d)) == 0 ? 0 : 1 ;
  }

  return n ;
}
```

However it perhaps makes more sense to generate a string as ASCII digits rather than an array of integers.

```
char* int2bin( int val, char* str )
{
    // Skip leading zeros
    int d = 0 ;
    for( d = 0; (val & (1<<d)) == 0 && d < 15; d++ )
    {
        // nothing
    }   

    // Significant digits
    for( int s = 0 ; d < 16; s++; d++ )
    {
        str[s] = (val & (1<<d)) == 0 ? '0' : '1' ;
    }    

    str[s] = 0 ;

    return str ;
}
```

Then the output is simply:

```
  char n[17] ;
  printf("%s", int2bin(var, n) ) ;
```